# Использование AJAX

Tags: ajax, html

Пытаюсь разобраться в Ajax.
Помогите найти фэйл :(
Должно работать так: вводишь текст в один инпут, выводится в другой.
А у меня во втором тупо содержимое страницы пишется (

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function ajaxFunction1(){
  $.post("task12.php", { "in" : $("#in1").val()},
  function(data){
     $("#out1").val(data);
  }, "text");
}
-->

</script>

Demo post metod<br>
Input text: <input type="text" onkeyup="ajaxFunction1();"
                name="in1" id="in1" />
ajax result: <input type="text" name="out1" id="out1" />
</form>
```

**Добавлено.**

task12.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> <html> <head>
<title> Task12</title>
<link href="style7.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> <!-- function ajaxFunction1(){ $.post("task10.php", { "in" : $("#in1").val()}, function(data){ $("#out1").val(data); }, "text"); } -->
</script>
<body>
<form> Demo post metod<br> Input text: <input type="text" onkeyup="ajaxFunction1();" name="in1" id="in1" /> ajax result: <input type="text" name="out1" id="out1" /> </form>
</div>
</body> </html>
```

Comment: Покажите task12.php

Comment: Вопрос!

 $.post("task12.php", { "in" : $("#in1").val()}

Зачем тогда у тебя в файле task12.php есть HTML?
Ты же должен в этом файле просто обработать полученные данные и отправить их обратно.

Comment: @Shrek, вот-вот, но тут вообще непойми, что у него) task12.php -> task10.php

Comment: @shrek, @Boolean я думал, что там пишет имя файла страницы, в которой формочка. Или надо иначе?

Это я тестил. Поставил task10.php. Там вообще должно быть task12. Всё равно не работает.

Comment: Там просто "голый" PHP, который у тебя получает данные и потом их отправляет обратно, никакого HTML там быть не должно!

Пример в ответе последнем!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На стороне клиента:

```
$.post(
  "/ajaxtest.php",
  {
    param1: "param1",
    param2: 2
  },
  onAjaxSuccess
);

function onAjaxSuccess(data)
{
  // Здесь мы получаем данные, отправленные сервером и выводим их на экран.
  alert(data);
}
```

На стороне сервера никакого HTML:

```
<?php
  // файл http://hostname/ajaxtest.php
  echo "I get param1 = ".$_POST['param1']." and param2 = ".$_POST['param1'];
?>
```

В ответ получишь строку `I get param1 = param1 and param2 = 2`.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему, в task12.php у вас выводится вся страница, а не только результат. Такое может происходить, например, при использовании шаблонизатора. Позаботьтесь о том, чтобы у вас выводилось только нужное значение, без всяких `<html>`-финтифлюшочек. Или извлекайте значение из элемента со страницы ответа:

```
data = $(data).find('#content').html();
$("#out1").val(data);
```

Comment: в task12.php собственно - страница с формой и скриптом. так ли должно быть?

Comment: Только СКРИПТ.

Comment: @Timmi55, там вообще ничего не должно быть, кроме нужного значения.